# Set rules in Firebase Realtime Database without using email/password auth system or generating JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Basically I want my login system to just be a unique key. I already know that the user will be the only person who knows their key, so the login page would basically just be one textbox (asking for the key) and a submit button.

I then want to be able to use that key in my rules to determine whether or not a user can access certain data.

I'm aware that I could change my login system to a username/password system, and store their key within an object with the Firebase UID, however this would make the app and rules more complicated than they need to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow someone to read the data if they know the key, you can allow that in your rules with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$key": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

So the above allows anyone to use any data they know the exact key off.

---

If you only want to allow this for a very specific key that is known when you write the rules, the equivalent would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "verySpecificKey": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now only that one single key is allowed, and the user will still need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a user key that they log in with is not natively supported by Firebase. However, you can fake this with the email password sign-in method.
All you do is append the user key with a `@appname.com` resulting in `myUniqueKey@firebaseApp.com`

You can then use a generic password for the user for unsecured solutions, or implement a short pin which I highly recommend, but to do so would require expanding the pin requirements by bloating it with a simple hash like md5.

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var password = crypto.createHash('md5').update(USER_PASSWORD).digest("hex");
```

This way, the user is a valid Firebase user that you can check with all security rules.

You can read about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth